# Refreshing an http request query?

Tags: php, request, httprequest, steam, steam-web-api

I am trying to pull data from the steam api for dota 2 matches but the api limits the returned matches to 500 total per query. I want to pull as many matches as possible like in the millions so doing it 500 at a time seems like its not gonna happen.

https://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/WebAPI/GetMatchHistory

here is some documentation on my request

Basically how it goes is: I make a request to get matches by some parameters, and 500 total are returned per query of which 100 are shown at a time. I then have to update my request url to add the latest match_id and begin my search there. From there the returned matches reduces by 100, so 500 -> 400 -> 300 etc... until 0.

I need way more than 500 but when I refresh my script I get 0 results remaining whenever my last match id is the same as the one in the same 'query'.

Can anyone help me out? My web app idea is 100% dependent on me getting as much games as possible.

Comment: @Satya 500 records per request, but if I refresh my request somehow it might work? I am not sure how to do this though

Comment: I just now checked the documentation and you can specify matches_requested  param to get N results. If you do not specify it will show 25 results only.

Comment: @Satya im not sure but i think that parameter is outdated because automatically it shows 100 at a time and 500 total, I added this and changed it to something over 100 and it made it 100, i changed it to 15 and it showed 15 so the max is 100 it seems like